# What algorithm is used to determine if the data is cacheble in an ARM Cortex-M0 (shown by the HPROT[3] signal bit)

Tags: arm, cpu-cache

as mentioned above, ARM Cortex-M0's HPROT[3] signal tell you if the data on the bus is cacheble or not. How is it decided by the MC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is decided based on the address used.

The documentation is your friend. 
Specifically http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0497a/CIHDHAEF.html.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm new to reading up documentation,so couldnt figure out where to look in that fat manual :D